# Understanding the repo to maturity trade

Tags: bond-yields

Apparently this trade may have caused MF Global to go under!

As I understand, this trade is simply a repo that ends at maturity of the bond.

And so, I think that the repo rate (assuming zero haircut) must equal the bond yield to maturity?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: see my last sentence....

Comment: what is so unclear about the question?  why did u "demote" it?

Comment: This will answer your question re MF Global specifically: http://blogs.reuters.com/felix-salmon/2011/11/01/what-happened-at-mf-global/

Comment: it says there "the rate at which it was borrowing money was lower than the coupon payments on the European sovereign bonds." but to me, it seems this implies an arbitrage opportunity () so the repo rate should go up untill it matches the bond yield and then there would be no more arb

Comment: In all seriousness, you should ask Mr. Corzine if there was an arbitrage there or not.

Comment: haha, so what - you are saying that there's such fear of liquidity risk from margin calls that people dont want to try do this huge arbitrage?